# How to show only root in JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` like this:

```
private TreeNode createNodes() {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode grandparent;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent;

        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("San Francisco");

        grandparent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Potrero Hill");
        root.add(grandparent);

        parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Restaurants");
        grandparent.add(parent);

        dummyParent = root;

        return root;
    }
```

I want to show only the root "San Francisco" in the screen not by default. Then the tree only expands when I click to the extended icon. How can I do that? I had tried to use some methods:

```
         tree.setRootVisible(true);
         tree.setShowsRootHandles(false);
```

Comment: JTree.collapsePath(TreePath path)

Comment: It also worked but i prefer Jtree.collapseRow(0). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show only the root "San Francisco" in the screen

After you have created the data and added the model to the tree you can use:

```
tree.collapseRow(0);
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for your sharing.